# Increasing Default number of partitions in Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

When we create a new Kafka topic automatically in Kafka the default number of partitions for that topic will be 1, since the configuration `num.partitions=1` .
Is there any ways to increase this property using any command or scripts without editing the `server.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

For updating the property you will have to modify the server.properties but  you can increase the partitions by using kafka admin scripts as below

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --alter --topic my_topic_name
  --partitions <number_of_partitions>
```

Comment: But this is for altering the topic already created. My question is how can we increase the default ´num.partitions´ property.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script called `create-topic.sh`:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper <ZK_HOST> --topic $1 --partitions <DEFAULT_NUM_TOPICS>
```

and force everyone to only make topics via this script:

```
./create-topic.sh <TOPIC_NAME>
```

This isn't a fantastic solution, but you're severely limited if you really can't change `server.properties`.

Comment: It can be a workaround. still, if I am using my program then it won't work, right?

Comment: You have a program that automatically creates Kafka topics? AFAIK you'd have to change `server.properties` to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka version 1.1, [dynamic broker configuration feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6240) is added. But, updating `num.partitions` config is not supported.